# Android: manual change date DatePicker

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I'm having trouble with the date picker.
Just when the user changes the year, he/she presses a button that takes you to the next screen. The problem here is that the year isn't set, it is set by default, and that's not correct. Can someone help me?

Comment: Why do you change the screen if the year is not set? 
How do you know he user forgot to set the date, or accidentally didn't?

Comment: the button assumes that everything is set, apparently the value is set when lost focus if is editted manually.

Answer (score 1):

i solved it by forcing focus to another object, like a TextView, then processing the info and moving to the next screen. thanks for your cooperation anyway.